# iplot.setExtendedQuery: How to display custom mouse over information?

Tags: r, mondrian, iplots

Concerning the superb [iplots package](http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/iplots/) in R:

By default, pressing CTRL and moving the mouse over a point in a scatter plot shows the x and y values of this point. **How can I extend this to also show other attributes, which are not part of the plot**, as shown [here](http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/mondrian/Mondrian.html#Scat) (see Mondrian screenshot) and as asked [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-April/128787.html), too?

In [Mondrian](http://www.rosuda.org/Mondrian/), this works perfectly well by selecting any attributes within the data overview window and then pressing CTRL + SHIFT on a data point in a scatter plot for example. In iPlots, there is no way to select the attributes like this. I thought `iplot.setExtendedQuery()` is the key. However, there are no examples on how to use the query string.

Selecting a point plus printing the attributes using sth in the veins of `mydata[iset.selected(), ]` can't be the only way to go...

[image]

Comment: Short answer: can't do it in stock iplots package (I checked the source). See the discussion at [this link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/query-labels-in-iplot-or-other-interactive-scatterplot-td4659918.html) for a way to do this outside of iplots. Two functions in the TeachingDemos package are recommended - HWidentify and HTKidentify. They can be modified to show mult-line attributes on mouseover.